# Fixed Position without Overlay?

Tags: position

i am trying to append a new Div to a Page with Javascript , i want to have it fixed but WITHOUT overlaying the page, it should look like a sidebar at the left side of the page, currently if i set it to position fixed, it appears but overlays the whole page, any idea how to fix this?

thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

By fixing an element, you're removing it from the normal flow of rendering, and hence the other elements act as if it isn't there. The best way to avoid this is to add padding to the actual content on the rest of the page, to pretend that the side menu is there.

```
div.menu {
position:fixed;
left:0px;
top:100px;
width:200px;
height:400px;
}
div.content {
padding-left:215px;
}
```

The padding-left pads the box 200px for the sidebar, plus 15 for a nice padding so the text isn't pressed up against the side.

```
<div class='menu'>Menu Here</div>
<div class='content'>
    Content<br />In<br />Here<br />Fits in place
</div>
```

Comment: Thx, well, my initial idea was tb´he same, unfortunately  it is harder to do than it sounds, so i am using this for a Safari Extension and everything gets injected, so redefining the DOW is quite much more trickier, i trieed adding a padding to the whole page excuding my DIV but with no luck, it doesnt work as expected currently... everything looks the same